# How can I create a custom command to search in Vim?

Tags: vim

I figured out how to search the file structure and it's really nice `:find **/my_file.txt`
This will find any file with the name my_file.txt. What I want to do is create a custom command so I can just say `:srch my_file.txt` so that I don't have to type out the entire find command each time. Any ideas how to do this? I found the

```
:command MyCommand find **/my_file.txt
```

but I can't figure out how to pass it a file that I enter

Comment: I just try it and it works, but I have a project with a deep directory structure, so Vim says: `E77: Too many file names`. Can I change the limit of search?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check `:h <args>` & co.

But, why don't you add ./** to `&path`? (and continue to use `:find` that supports autocompletion, instead of implementing it by yourself)

Comment: Mostly because I don't know how :-)